# compare different datasets with stacked bar graphs in R

Tags: r

I need to compare two different methods that each of them has 3 different results in one graph with using stacked bar style.

I want to draw a plot so that x axis shows the experiment and y axis shows results. and each bar fills with 3 results in stacked bar format.

```
experiment method resuult1 result2 result3
1            m1      1        2       3 
1            m2      4        5       6
2            m1      7        8       9
2            m2     10        11      12
3            m1     13        14      15
3            m2     16        17      18
```

I have this code for comparing two data set how can i change it.

```
library(ggplot2);
pdf(file = '$filename.pdf', width=5, height=5);
data1 <- as.matrix(read.table('$INPUT_FILE1', header = T));
data1.experiment <- as.numeric(data1[,\"Experiment\"]);
data1.obs <- as.numeric(data1[,\"Result1\"]);
data1.method <- as.factor(data1[,\"Method\"]);
df <- data.frame(data1.experiment, data1.method, data1.obs);
```

orderlist = c("70", "100", "130", "160", "190", "260");

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = data1.experiment, y = data1.obs, fill = data1.method), ylim=c(60000, 2800000)) + 
    geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')+
    labs(x='$xlabel',y='$ylabel', fill='Methods') + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c('red','blue'), labels = c('DTB-MAC', 'IEEE802.11P')) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = orderlist)+
    theme(legend.position = c(1, 1), legend.justification = c(1, 1), legend.background     = element_rect(colour = NA, fill = 'white'));
```

Comment: "give me the code ... " ? What have you tried/where have you looked so far?

Answer (score 2):

You said that you need to compare the methods. If you represent experiment on x-axis and result on y then how will you represent method??? My way of doing it is using the facet. Here is the code for how to do it using ggplot2.

```
dat <- read.csv("data.csv")
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
dat1 <- melt(dat,id.vars = c("experiment","method"))
p <- ggplot(dat1,aes(experiment,value,fill=variable))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+
      facet_wrap(~method,nrow=1)
p
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 0):

This sort of multi-dimensional chart is best explored using the `ggplot2` package. I will assume here that the data you have pasted is stored in the data.frame `d`:

```
require(reshape2)    ## needed to have all experiments in one variable
require(ggplot2)     ## needed for the great vizualizations

d <- melt(d, id.vars=c("experiment", "method"))
ggplot(d, aes(x=factor(experiment), y=value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  facet_wrap(~method)
```

You can polish the graph further using custom labels, but that is too long to explore here. The questions with the `ggplot2` tag have lots of great examples.

EDIT: Corrected to show the methods too, as already answered by @user2743244